# Django models field user and admin from the same model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model User and this other model where the admin and the users are from the same model User.

```
admin = models.ForeignKey(User)
users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I get this error:

```
ERRORS:
admin: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'admin' clashes with reverse accessor for 'users'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'admin' or 'users'.
users: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'users' clashes with reverse accessor for 'admin'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'users' or 'admin'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change code like this:

```
admin = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='admin_user')
users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users_user')
```

Also see [ForeignKey related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating different users attributes with the same backwards relationships
'user_set', and this doesn't works.

Try it:

```
admin = models.ForeignKey(User)
users = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="+")
```

provide two different related_name attributes so that the backwards relationship attributes' names don't clash.

In this post, you can see the same problem:
[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764184/django-migrations-how-to-make-it-forget?noredirect=1#comment53368873_32764184)

The [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects):